# Show that the power series is solution to f ''(x) + f(x) = 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

is a solution of:
$$f''(x)+f(x)=0$$

---

It seems that $f''x$ is just $-f(x)$ $=>$ $-f(x)+f(x)=0$, but when I try to get the solution  I get a weird power series that is not $-f(x)$. Can anyone tell me what went wrong? See below:

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}*(2n)}{(2n)!}$$
 $$f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^∞ \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-2}*(2n)*(2n-1)}{(2n)!}$$

$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^{2n+2}*(2n+4)*(2n+3)}{(2n+4)!}$$
 $$=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$$

Anyone know what mistake I made? I need $f''(x)$ to be $-f(x)$

---

Answer (score 1):

You have made mistakes in changing $n$ to $n+2$. In $f''(x)$, $x^{2n-2}$ the becomes $x^{2n+2}$ and $(2n)(2n-1)$ becomes $(2n+4)(2n+3)$. Also $(2n)!$ becomes $(2n+4)!$

Answer for the edited version. To compare your series for $f''(x)$ with the series for $f(x)$ you have to change $n$ to $n-1$ (so that $x^{2n+2}$ becomes $x^{2n}$).

Comment: Why does $x^{2n-2}$  become $x^{2n+2}$? I already added 2 to $n$ as I changed the index from n=2 to n = 0

Comment: When you change $n$ to $n+2$ you get $2(n+2)-2=2n+4-2=2n+2$. You have to check all your computations carefully.

Comment: @Jtheconstant Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but when I replace every n term with (n+1), it makes the power series look very different than f(x), since the power series is supposed to be -f(x), so that it cancels with f(x) becoming 0

Comment: I just noticed that changing n to n-1 will give the right answer, but why do I have to change n to n-1? I know it's so f''(x) will match f(x), but it seems random to do that, or not the correct method to do that

Comment: Strange comment. If it gives the right answer just do it. @Jtheconstant

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the question asked to prove $f''(x)+f(x)=0$, which would mean $f''(x)$ should be $-f(x)$ in order for the differential equation to be satisfied. So I think using the given function $f(x)$ to find $f''(x)$, then changing the index back to 0, should do the trick. But changing $n$ to $n-1$ as you suggested, seems random, in which if it were represented in the index, I would be making my index $n=0$ to $n=1$, which does not match the original $f(x)$

Comment: I think obtaining the answer is more difficult than this. I don't think you can just take the current answer and just change $n$ to $n-1$ without any reason. Even though it leads to the correct answer, I think it is a coincidence

Comment: When the I take the second derivative, the index of the summation becomes $n=2$. Then changing the index once again, from $n=2$ back to $n=0$, so that it matches $f(x)$, makes sense. But then after that, randomly changing $n$ to $n-1$ and not changing the index once again, does not seem like the right method to use

Comment: And one last note, is that changing $n$ to $n-1$ does not lead to the correct answer unless I ignore the index of the summation, which seems entirely wrong to do. This is because when I replace $n$ with $n-1$, the index would also change, from $n=0$ to $n=1$, which does not give the right answer

Answer (score -1):

‘’ has to star with n=1 not n=2. And be more careful when reindexing to 0, alternating power will switch by 1, x power by two.